# how to get code diff from code inspector

Tags: javascript, html, css, chromium, web-inspector

Using chrome code inspector is super helpful, but after modifying the code inside it (css, html) to see result live, I realize that I got to get the code difference which is sometimes too painful mainly after modifying the css of many html tags.

Is there any chromium extension for that?

THanks,

Comment: you can actually do this with the built-in dev tools using the Resource features and setting up a local resource folder where the modified copies live. It's not intuitive using the menus to figure out how to do this, but it's possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out these two extensions for css editing tools in google chrome browser

[Live CSS Editor](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/live-css-editor/oelggcmknbjmhkpgjfhakedcfnkgbdpg?hl=en)

[Save CSS](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/save-css/mflkegihknjnhmpfnaimpfkjbkelhhkf)

Comment: That's quite what I'm looking for, thx